# Is Isaiah 50:6 literally fulfilled in Jesus?

Tags: jesus, isaiah, messiah

> Isaiah 50:6 I offered My back to those who struck Me,
>
> and My cheeks to those who tore out My beard.
>
> I did not hide My face from scorn and spittle.

Was this literally fulfilled in Jesus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Isaiah 50 has often been taken as a Messianic prophecy (I'm offering a New Testament interpretation of an Old Testament text).

Although we do not have direct New Testament discussion of anyone plucking out the hairs of His beard, the other parallels to Jesus are quite clear:

- Back: John 19:1
- Cheeks: Matt 26:67
- Scorn: Luke 23:35
- Spittle: Matt 26:67

Jesus bore the cruel physical and emotional abuse prophesied by Isaiah.

Comment: All true. You might also point out that Christ enumerates much of this same humiliation (and torture) in Luke 18:32. +1.

Comment: Another good simple answer.  Many thanks